# decompose an HTML list with page fragments

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, xpath, page-objects

*note:  Looking for simplest possible example of `PageFactory` and fragments.  I've been referencing an article which uses additional libraries I wasn't aware of.*

The [desired](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) structure:

[image: martin fowler]

Where there's an "Album Page" and "Album List" page.  I'm attempting to deal with the "Album List Page", except for [books](http://books.toscrape.com/).

Struggling with [composition](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/37069/8900), the `HomePage` constructor [employs](http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/) `PageFactory` by invoking `initElements` with the `WebDriver` instance it receives.  What should be passed to the `Catalog` instance?  Just the `WebElement` for the desired fragment, here `sideCategoryContainer`?

```
HomePage(WebDriver webDriver) {
    LOG.fine(webDriver.getCurrentUrl());
    this.webDriver = webDriver;
    PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, this);
    LOG.fine(sideCategoryXPath);
    WebElement sideCategoryContainer = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(sideCategoryXPath));
    LOG.fine(sideCategoryContainer.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    Catalog catalogueFragment = new Catalog(sideCategoryContainer);
}
```

when a `Catalog` object is instantiated, does it need a `WebDriver` reference to invoke `initElements` through `PageFactory`?  Or, is that implicit with the `WebElement` which is received in the constructor?

```
package dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Catalog {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Catalog.class.getName());
private WebElement container = null;
private final String listItem = "//ul";

@FindBy(xpath = "//ul/li/ul/li/a")
private final List<WebElement> listItems = null;

private Catalog() {
}

public Catalog(WebElement container) {
    this.container = container;
    LOG.info(container.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    PageFactory.initElements((WebDriver) this.container, this);
    WebElement items = container.findElement(By.xpath(listItem));
    Category categoryFragment = new Category(items);
}

public void iterate() {
    LOG.fine(container.toString());
    LOG.fine(container.getTagName());
    LOG.fine(container.getText());
    LOG.fine(container.getLocation().toString());
    for (WebElement webElement : listItems) {
        LOG.fine(webElement.getText());
        LOG.info(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

}

The notion being that a `Catalog` instance receives just a fragment, just an `HTML` list which it will iterate, passing each item, in turn, to a `Category` object.  Just as it received its `container`, then `Catalog` will pass a `container` of `WebElement` to a `Category` instance, [as](https://seleniumjava.com/2018/01/07/use-streams-for-lists-of-web-elements/):

[image: streams]

but, first, `HomePage` has to pass a fragment of `HTML` to its `Catlog` instance, which then will iterate the list, as above, passing each list fragment to a new `Category` object.

Below, the `Catalog` instance receives the `container` correctly, because it's able to output the `HMTL` list.

```
Executing: gradle :run
Arguments: [-PcmdLineArgs=, -PjvmLineArgs=, -c, /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium/settings.gradle.kts]

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :run
1546003872486   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.PfcniQDUAugm"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1546003874033   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1546003874034   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1546003878803   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 32943
1546003878818   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Dec 28, 2018 5:31:18 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Dec 28, 2018 5:31:35 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog <init>
INFO: 


                    <li>
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html">

                                Travel

                        </a>

                        </li>


..

                    <li>
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/crime_51/index.html">

                                Crime

                        </a>

                        </li>


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog.<init>(Catalog.java:26)
    at dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.HomePage.<init>(HomePage.java:26)
    at dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.App.scrapeBooks(App.java:22)
    at dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.App.main(App.java:16)

> Task :run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :run
```

What I run into is that in order to iterate the list `initElements` needs to be invoked -- yet, seemingly, this creates an error.

The documentation I found on this:

> If you notice, I still use ‘FindBy‘ annotation. But instead of using
>   plain WebElement, I use the Page fragments classes we have created.
>   Above Google Search page object looks better than how it would have
>   been if we had considered all the elements of the page in one single
>   class. As you see we do NOT use any ‘new‘ keyword to create an
>   instance of the fragments. Graphene makes it easy for us by
>   automatically injecting the instance of the page fragments on the fly
>   and delegates the behaviors of the page to the corresponding page
>   fragment classes.

I'm not sure what `Graphene` [is](http://arquillian.org/arquillian-graphene/) but I'm not inclined to add it at this point; trying to keep it as simple as possible.  Unless **adding** Graphene increases the simplicity for me??

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I was referencing an article which uses `graphene`:  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/37081/8900  so I went down a false path a bit.  Cannot grok **how** to use composition with the POM.  I'm trying to just iterate through a `HTML` list, but utilizing the POM.

Comment: Try to keep your questions atomic and complete on its own - people are not looking on all the questions all the time. I would suggest you to re-write the question to mention exactly what you want to iterate, so that people can suggest a refactoring.