# POM: driver is passed as an argument? Always?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, page-objects, page-factory

Example [code](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/):

> Driver is being passed as an Argument so that Selenium is able to
>   locate the element on the browser (driver).
>
> Element is returned, so that an Action can be performed on it.
>
> Method is declared as Public Static, so that it can be called in any
>   other method without instantiate the class.
>
> Follow the same rule for creating LogIn Page class.

So each and every single fragment, using the POM, always gets a `WebDriver` reference?  Each and every fragment might then invoke 
`PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)`?

Just trying narrow down an overly broad, [sprawling](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/37069/8900), question.

If each POM, each fragment, is as:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class LogIn_Page {
    private static WebElement element = null;

    public static WebElement txtbx_UserName(WebDriver driver){
         element = driver.findElement(By.id("log"));
         return element;
    }

     public static WebElement txtbx_Password(WebDriver driver){
         element = driver.findElement(By.id("pwd"));
         return element;
    }

     public static WebElement btn_LogIn(WebDriver driver){
         element = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
         return element;
    }
}
```

then it's all `static` all the way down, is it not?  How can this be refactored so that `static` isn't relied on so extensively, the `POM` is followed, and, as a bonus, `PageFactory` is employed?

Here's a [sample](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/selenium/selenium-page-object-model-tutorial/) using `PageFactory`:

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "username")
private WebElement userName;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "password")
private WebElement password;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "login-btn")
private WebElement login;

public void logIn(String userName, String password) {
    this.userName.sendKeys(userName);
    this.password.sendKeys(password);
    this.login.click();
}
```

Let's say that this `LoginPage` wanted to create a page fragment, using the `PageFactory` which the `POM` utilized, how would it do so?

Comment: where is the "refactor my code to make it good" button?  Meant in jest.  I'm just trying to understand `PageFactory` usage and the `POM`.  I'm not literally asking someone to come along and fix my code.  Nor figuratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate that author's contribution to the people's global knowledge sharing but I have doubt on how well he mastered his Java skills at least because of he doesn't adhere coding style convention that discourages snake_case style. Nobody also uses capitalized letters in package names. So I wouldn't rely on that or at least I would treat that with certain level of skepticism.

Moving to your question I'd like to spotlight the following:

- Basically each of the fields in your example with `PageFactory` represent a fragment. So if you want your page to provide a page fragment you just introduce `getter` method to your page.
- Using `PageFactory` approach lets you shortcut the way of fragmenting the page

However there are still some advantages in the first approach like:

- you can parameterize locators which you cannot do with `PageFactory` approach since annotations cannot have dynamic values
- It is easier to troubleshoot and analyze stacktrace since when you use reflection a lot of logic is built in runtime so you wouldn't have the "line where the issue happened".

Summing up, `PageFactory` approach seems to be enough since you can describe a fragment as annotated field and just provide it for outer world using getters.

Comment: It was just the first example I found, but, yeh.  Second one in q is better source.  When using `PageFactory` the instance **must** be initialized and so a driver reference **must** get passed in?

Comment: @Thufir the instance of what?

Comment: Good q. an instance of LoginPage would need a WebDriver reference to use PageFactory?  So, **any** fragment employing PageFactory also needs a WebDriver reference?  As a matter of practice, where does the reference originate?  In the application driver classes main method?

Comment: @Thufir This depends. If you utilize unit test frameworks, you don't have a `main` class. You rather have test classes which are controlled by a framework using reflection mechanism. In such the case you may have your driver as the field of your test class and instantiate it in `@Before` method. Then you instantiate your pages within a test and pass driver object there.Another way is to implement `Singleton` pattern-a special class that would expose static method that would return `WebDriver`.The specific is that when invoked the first time it creates an object and then just returns ready one.

Comment: @Thufir this might be the topic for a separate question.

Comment: I didn't know any of that, and know nothing about testing.  But, I can see how that works a bit now.  Sort of.